# Can a variational auto-encoder learn images composed of random noise at each pixel (each drawn from the same distribution)?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, probability-distribution, variational-autoencoder

Can a variational auto-encoder (VAE) learn images whose pixels have been generated from a Gaussian distribution (e.g. $N(0, 1)$), i.e. each pixel is a sample from $N(0, 1)$?

My gut feeling says no, because the VAE adds additional noise $\epsilon$ to the original image in the latent space, and if all images and pixels are random from the same distribution it would be impossible do decode/reconstruct into the particular input image. However, VAEs are a bit of a mystery to me internally. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! The $\epsilon$ that you're talking about probably refers to the sample drawn from $N(0,1)$ during the forward pass of the encoder. This is the so-called "re-parametrization trick", i.e. you do not sample directly from the latent space (i.e. you do not sample directly $z$, i.e. a latent representation of the image), but you sample $\epsilon$, then you combine it with the mean and variance of the distribution of the latent space to produce $z$. Why? Because this apparently makes training more stable (i.e. it's a variance reduction technique).

Comment: @nbro I see, thanks for the explanation! So in this case, would it be that the VAE can actually learn these images composed of random pixels?

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous what you mean by "images composed of random noise at each pixel (each drawn from, say N(0, 1))"? Do you mean that 1. you add a sample from N(0, 1) to each pixel of the original image (i.e. you add Gaussian noise to some image, e.g. a face of a person), or 2. every pixel is drawn from $N(0, 1)$ (i.e. you generate the images really by drawing a sample from $N(0, 1)$)? I believe it's option two. Anyway, by "random", one usually means draw from the uniform distribution.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you can learn images whose pixels have been generated from a uniform distribution. In general, in those cases, there will be no pattern to learn (i.e. anything to compress). Have a look at information entropy. However, there are denoising auto-encoders. These can reconstruct the original inputs (i.e. not the noisy ones), but the noisy inputs are "just" noisy  (i.e. there are still patterns in those noisy images), so they are not uniformly randomly generated.

Comment: @nbro yes, sorry, it is 2, every pixel is random Gaussian noise. From what you're saying, it can't learn a pattern because there is none? What if we were to use a latent space of size equal to the input space size, would it be able to learn then?

Comment: I was talking about the case where pixels are generated from a uniform distribution, not from a normal distribution. Anyway, note that N(0, 1) doesn't restrict the values of the pixels to be in the range [0, 1].

Comment: Why did you delete this post and the other? I can delete it again, but I just wanted to understand why.

Comment: @nbro Question wasn't well-posed and the other one was absolutely all over the place as you pointed out, as a result I guess it got overlooked by people who may have been able to answer and didn't get much interaction at all. I think I'm going to get my ideas sorted, and post a more precise and thought-out question tomorrow that should be easier to answer and understand for people. I'll see you then!

Comment: This question is actually interesting, but feel free to delete it again if you want. Your other post was also interesting, although it needed clarification initially and you were asking too many things. Try to ask more specific questions next time and ask only one question per post. If you have multiple questions, ask each of them in its separate post.  Also, note that you may not receive an answer, but it doesn't mean your question is not interesting. Our community is still small, but, hopefully, we will grow and provide more help.

Comment: @nbro sounds good, let's keep this one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAE's try and model the **distribution** of your data. So it's not going to learn " images composed of random noise at each pixel" *per se* (though, if overfitting, it could remember them). But it would be very capable of learning the simple noise **distribution** from which you sampled your random pixels

Comment: The question is not well-posed, so you should have waited for clarification before answering.

Comment: I think the question is well posed, you seemed not to have understood it the way I did, is all :) the user seems to wonder if there's something to learn from noise and I believe my answer answered just that

Comment: Yes, I admit that I missed one part. But it's still not clear whether the user wants to know about 1. images whose pixels have been generated from $N(0, 1)$ or 2. images to which we have added Gaussian noise. These are two different things! In one case, we are just corrupting the image, in the other case, we are really generating "Gaussian images".

Comment: I really understand the question as being about 1 => "composed of random noise at each pixel" ; but only they can actually answer that, true

Comment: Indeed, I meant 1), images are generated where each pixel is Gaussian noise, before anything to do with the VAE. Sorry @nbro for not being clear!

Comment: @ted if it were to learn the simple noise (standard normal) distribution, would it still be able to decompress/decode from the latent space accurately to the original image? Because of the introduction of random noise, reparameterization trick, wouldn't the latent space effectively look like a completely different one of those images (with pixels still from the standard normal)?

Comment: I think you're confused by epsilon, it's a sampling procedure not a noise added to the latent representation or anything, it's very different from the generating process of your data

Comment: @ted that makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: @ted what if the latent space were the same size as the input, would it learn the distribution better than if it had to compress under these circumstances?

Comment: @ted Well, the pixels of the "random images" are also sampled, so I understand the confusion of the OP.